# Plotting a long route on Google map v2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

One of my Application's features need to show the track history of a vehicle on map. In order to implement this feature I am using Google Road API. I am passing 100 lat lng points to it but the resulting response is not on road. it contains many jumps.
 Is there any other API which gives the better response? And is it it possible to plot those points on google map?Help required.
Thanks.﻿